# how to extract the required information from the spark UI to spark application?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and need some help. I want to do the monitoring of my spark application but do not want to use spark UI/History server. Is there any way to pull out the DAG graph from the spark UI into the spark application code?

If we can not pull the exact DAG. Can I get all info on console window or in a text file?